# Printing the longest string from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the purpose of this script is to take user inputs and then print the longest input the user entered when a blank line is input

(think of "" as the way the user breaks the loop instead of printing 'stop')

at the moment in only prints the first non-capital letter, and as I'm extremely new to this I'm completely lost on how to resolve it

```
loopEnd = ""

n = (input("Input: "))
longString = max(n)

while n != loopEnd:
    n = str(input("Input: "))
    if n == loopEnd:
        print("Longest input was", "'",longString,"'")
```

Comment: You never reassign `longString`

Comment: by default `input()` is `str`, so no need to convert it. `(input("Input: "))` is converting it into `tuple` I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
long_input = ''
max_len = 0
val = True
while val:
    n = input()
    if n=='':
        val = False
    if len(n)>max_len:
        long_input = n
        max_len = len(n)

print("longest user input was {} having length of {} character".format(long_input, max_len))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
longest = ""
while True:
    n = input("Input: ")
    if n:
        if len(n) > len(longest):
            longest = n
    else:
        break

print(f"Longest input was '{longest}'")
```